# Relational data and NoSQL Use Case

Tags: sql, mongodb, couchdb, database, nosql

I am looking at building a system which allows people to input times that represent when they were working.
The database will store organisations which has users and projects.

- Organisations

  - Projects

    - Project a
    - Project b
  - Users

    - User c
    - User d

I also store records which have a start and end time associated to a particular project.

- Record

  - Start Time
  - End Time
  - Notes
  - Project
  - User

Now my question is related to the database.
I know this is inherently relational data so a relational database would make sense however, i have heard that nosql databases are good for flexibility and scalability when records grow.

Ultimately, I would like this system to become a service organisations can use therefore the number of organisation, users and records would grow tremendously (hopefully), so is there a case for using a nosql database?

I have looked at document-based databases such as mongoDB and couchDB.
Which apparently are good for profiles of users and organisation, but I do not see if there is any real benefit of using nosql when there will be queries to get all the records associated to an organisation/user or records from particular time periods/projects.

I would appreciate any advise you could give to aid my decision.

Comment: You already answered your own question: Structured data is better handled by a Relational DBMS, NoSQL is more suited for unstructured data.

Comment: But there are instances of relational data stored using nosql such as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740246/nosql-system-to-save-relational-data).I am unsure to when it is a definitely wrong to use a nosql and when it could be deemed acceptable with relational data.

Comment: The best case for NoSQL is one huge table, as soon as you need multiple joins and your queries get more complex you better go for Relational. Most Relational DBMSes can also access data in Hadoop, so you can get best of both worlds :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, use what makes sense. The below use cases (taken from a Pluralsight course on NoSQL) indicate that your project would make the most sense to use a Relational Database

- Line of Business: Relational
- Large consumer sites: NoSQL

---

- Complex data structure: Relational
- Big Data: NoSQL

---

- Transactional: Relational
- Content Management: NoSQL

---

- Enterprise: Relational
- Consumer Web: NoSQL